# Should I pass a collection as a property or retrieve it via Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, reactjs

I have a Rails app and recently integrated react. I am facing multiple situations where I need to pass an array of objects to react. So far I have done this via properties, something like :

```
react_component 'Comments', data: @comments
```

Where `@comments` is created in the controller.

Another approach would be to use ajax get request to obtain `@comment`s as json.

I would like to know the advantages and disadvantages of each approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you establish your data model in the controller, you're making a contract between react and rails, saying that this is the entirety of the data you will need (before switching to another route).  If you establish  your data model via ajax calls to an independent API route, you're able to update and extend your data as the user moves through the application, without needing to reach out to the rails app for another brand new MVC collection.

In either case, I would recommend taking a look at Flux.  I'm partial to the Redux implementation, but any flux pattern is a good way to manage data as it travels throughout the frontend of your app.